# Elastic Beanstalk ignoring .ebextensions for Datadog config in WAR deployment

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, datadog, ebextensions

I've looked at everything I can seem to find and nothing has really helped make progress. I'm trying to get Elastic Beanstalk to recognize and process the `99datadog.config` file in order to set up application profiling. Our app is deployed as a WAR, and the `.ebextensions` directory is at the top of it. The file structure looks like this:

```
/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/
  --api/
    --.ebextensions/
      --99datadog.config
    --META-INF
    --WEB-INF
  --api.war/
  --ROOT/
  --ROOT.war
```

The datadog config can be found here: https://docs.datadoghq.com/config/99datadog.config

We've got a different webapp that is structured the same way and the `.ebextensions` work there, which is even more confusing to me.

I've checked the `cfn-init-cmd.log` (and all the other logs for that matter) and can't find any mention of it even trying to run anything from that file.

Any ideas?